# How to compare contents of encrypted files on decentralized system?

Tags: encryption, privacy

I have three people: Alice, Bob, and Eva. Lets say Alice and Bob both want to share the same information with Eva, but we don't want Eva to know what the information is, and Alice and Bob don't want anyone to know what their secret is. How can we approach encryption so that the information XYZ is encrypted differently for Bob and Alice (ie, they can't compare results to figure out the source), but Eva can figure out they are equal without being able to de-encrypt them to the base state and know the information.

There is no in between, Eva connects directly with Bob and Alice, but Bob and Alice have no connection.

Comment: It sounds to me like Eva wants to deduplicate encrypted data. Unfortunately this isn't possible with strong cryptography (barring blocks duplicated by random chance), especially since there are multiple keys and Eva doesn't know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether two pieces of ciphertext can be compared to glean information, no. The whole point of encryption is to maximize [information theoretic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theoretic_security), or in other words, minimizing the amount of information revealed by a ciphertext about the cleartext upon cryptanalysis. [Ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability), a property of modern public key cryptosystems, is also relevant here. Essentially, the ciphertexts resulting from two pieces of text being encrypted with the same cipher should **not have a guessable correlation with their original plaintexts.**

Seeing as they have no mutual communication, you could ask Alice and Bob to provide signed hashes of the cleartext to prove they know the same information (without revealing the actual information), but there's little you can do with ciphertext.